# Using Select Case with InStr for multiple named sheets

Tags: excel, vba

My first post here.....
I was able to search and find this code from Siddharth Rout which is the basis for what I want to do....append multiple sheets of data to a single data sheet.  However I'm having trouble modifying it to fit my case. What I have below doesn't currently work......

Problem 1) How can I use Select Case InStr with multiple sheets (3) that do not have a common name such as "Legende" as the original poster had in her case.

Problem 2) In my case each sheet will have different columns that I need copied to the Tab_Appended sheet, Sheet1 will have x rows and I want column B, D, M, AR, etc and Sheet2 will have XXXX rows and I want to copy column B, D, N, AS, AT, etc for 15 sheets.

Credit to Siddharth Rout for this original code:

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsOLr As Long, wsLr As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'~~> Set this to the sheet where the output will be dumped
Set wsOutput = Sheets("Tab_Appended")

With wsOutput
    '~~> Get Last Row in "Tab_Appended" in Col A/M and Add 1 to it
    wsOLr = .Range("A:M").Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
            Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row + 1

    '~~> Loop through sheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        '~~> Check if the sheet name has Legende
        'Select Case InStr(1, ws.Name, "Legende", vbTextCompare)
        Select Case InStr(1, ws.Name, "Test2", vbTextCompare) + _
        InStr(1, strData, "Test", vbTextCompare) + _
        InStr(1, strData, "Sheet2", vbTextCompare)

        '~~> If not then
        Case 0
            With ws
                '~~> Get Last Row in the sheet
                wsLr = .Range("A:M").Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

                '~~> Copy the relevant range
                .Range("A2:M" & wsLr).Copy wsOutput.Range("A" & wsOLr)

                '~~> Get Last Row AGAIN in "Tab_Appended" in Col A/B and Add 1 to it
                wsOLr = wsOutput.Range("A:M").Find(What:="*", After:=wsOutput.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
            End With
        End Select
    Next
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Problem 1 - what is the logic for selecting the sheets? Problem 2 - perhaps store an array of columns relating to each sheet.

Comment: Edit of my comments...
Problem 1: There are 18 sheets total, the first 3 (Test2, Test, Sheet2) are sheets that I don't want to copy to the Tab-Appended sheet.  I just need various columns of data from the other 15 sheets.  Siddharth was able to avoid that with his Select Case InStr code because in that case all 3 sheets had the text "Legende" in the Tab name...not so in my case.
Problem 2: Thanks for the suggestion...I will look for that solution.
Please excuse me if I didn't understand your first question correctly.

Comment: I was trying to see if there was some logic to the sheets to be included. You could loop through the sheets and exclude those by three by name? In your code what is `strData`? If you replace that with `ws.name` the loop might work.

Comment: Thank you SJR.  Your second set of eyes caught an earlier copy-paste error, strData should have been ws.name.  Once changed the macro processed, but with some unexpected results.  With only 1 sheet name to be excluded, the macro loops thru all the remaining sheets and copies the Range A:M of each sheet once.  With all 3 sheet names excluded, it copies the Range A:M of each remaining sheet twice.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just forget to clear the results of the first run? I can't see a reason why it should do it twice.gfgf

Comment: Actually I think it's because you don't exclude Tab Appended from your loop.

Comment: Thanks SJR!  That was the fix.  I do wonder why Tab_Appended didn't need to be excluded when the there was just 1 exclusion tho'?  But your fix does resolve the issue....Thanks again for the teaching/learning experience!.